# If $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_{j}(N)$ exists does $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{N} f_{j}(N)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

If not, what additional conditions would be necessary for this to hold?

Edit: I've realised it's false:

$f_{j}(N) = \begin{cases} 1 & j \leq N \\ -N & j = N+1 \\ 0  & j > N \end{cases}$

My question in the body still stands about conditions under which this does hold.

Comment: One pretty obvious sufficient condition for it to be true is if $f_j(N)\geq0$ for all $j$ and all $N$

Comment: @Lorago: even that's not enough. Consider when $f_j(j-1)=1$ and $f_j(n)=0$ otherwise (with $f_1$ being the zero function).

Comment: @GregMartin in your case the limit exists, as $\sum_{j=1}^N f_j(N) = 0$.

Comment: @mihaild Fair enough, but here's a fix: keep my definition if $j$ is even, otherwise change to $f_j(j-1)=f_j(j)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Sufficient condition will be if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(N)$ converges uniform in $N$, ie $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists A \forall N \forall B > A: |\sum_{j=A}^B F_j(N)| < \varepsilon$ (if you switch order of $A$ and $N$, you get that the series converges for any $N$).

$$\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N f_j(N) =\\
 \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} (\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(N) - \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty f_j(N)) =\\
 \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(N) - \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty f_j(N)$$

Existence of the first limit is given, expression under the second limit can be made arbitrary small for large $N$ because convergence is uniform.

We can actually reformulate the problem to simplify a bit: let $a_N = \sum_{j = 1}^N f_j(N)$ and $b_N = \sum_{j = N + 1}^\infty f_j(N)$. Then $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty f_j(N) = a_N + b_N$, we are given that $\lim_{N \to \infty} a_N + b_N$ exists, and are asked if $\lim_{N \to \infty} a_N$ exists. This is, of course, equivalent to existence of $\lim_{N \to \infty} b_N$. Uniform convergence implies $b_N \to 0$, but we can of course have many other options.